# Field templateEngine in MailComponent required a bean of type 'org.thymeleaf.TemplateEngine' that could not be found

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc

Im new in Spring So, i have a problem like this:
Description:

Field templateEngine in com.diet4you.LapkoEkaterina.MailComponent required a bean of type 'org.thymeleaf.TemplateEngine' that could not be found.

The injection point has the following annotations:
    - @org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)

The following candidates were found but could not be injected:
    - Bean method 'templateEngine' in 'ThymeleafAutoConfiguration.ThymeleafDefaultConfiguration' not loaded because @ConditionalOnBean (types: org.thymeleaf.spring5.ISpringTemplateEngine; SearchStrategy: all) found beans of type 'org.thymeleaf.spring5.ISpringTemplateEngine' templateEngine
    - Bean method 'templateEngine' in 'ThymeleafAutoConfiguration.ThymeleafReactiveConfiguration' not loaded because did not find reactive web application classes

Action:

Consider revisiting the entries above or defining a bean of type 'org.thymeleaf.TemplateEngine' in your configuration.

**MailComponent:**

```
@Component
public class MailComponent {
    @Autowired
    MailSender mailSender;

    @Autowired
    JavaMailSender javaMailSender;

    @Autowired
    TemplateEngine templateEngine;

    public boolean sendSimpleMail(Contact contact) {
        SimpleMailMessage mailMessage = new SimpleMailMessage();
        mailMessage.setFrom(contact.getEmail());
        mailMessage.setSubject(contact.getSubject());
        mailMessage.setText(contact.getMessage());
        mailMessage.setTo("email@email.com"); // if you use Gmail do not forget to put your personal address

        try {
            mailSender.send(mailMessage);
            return true;
        } catch (MailException e) {
            System.err.println(e.getMessage());
            return false;
        }
    }

    public boolean sendHtmlMail(Contact contact) {

        Context context = new Context();
        context.setVariable("contact", contact);
        final String messageHtml = templateEngine.process("email/contact", context);

        MimeMessage mimeMessage = javaMailSender.createMimeMessage();
        MimeMessageHelper mailMessage = new MimeMessageHelper(mimeMessage);
        try {
            mailMessage.setTo("email@email.com"); // if you use Gmail do not forget to put your personal address
            mailMessage.setFrom(contact.getEmail());
            mailMessage.setSubject(contact.getSubject());
            mailMessage.setText(messageHtml, true);
            javaMailSender.send(mimeMessage);
            return true;
        } catch (MessagingException | MailException e) {
            System.err.println(e.getMessage());
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

**MailConfig:**

```
@PropertySource(ignoreResourceNotFound = true, value = "classpath:ValidationMessages.properties")
@Configuration
public class MailConfig {

    @Value("${spring.mail.host}")
    private String host;

    @Value("${spring.mail.port}")
    private int port;

    @Value("${spring.mail.default-encoding}")
    private String encoding;

    @Value("${spring.mail.properties.mail.debug}")
    private String debug;

    /**
     * Gmail Config
     */
//    @Value("${spring.mail.username}")
//    private String username;
//    @Value("${spring.mail.password}")
//    private String password;
//    @Value("${spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.auth}")
//    private String auth;
//    @Value("${spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.starttls.enable}")
//    private String starttls;

    @Bean
    public JavaMailSender javaMailSender() {
        JavaMailSenderImpl mailSender = new JavaMailSenderImpl();
        mailSender.setDefaultEncoding(encoding);
        mailSender.setHost(host);
        mailSender.setPort(port);

        /**
         * Gmail Config
         */
//        mailSender.setUsername(username);
//        mailSender.setPassword(password);
        Properties properties = new Properties();
//        properties.put("mail.smtp.auth", auth);
//        properties.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", starttls);
        properties.put("mail.debug", debug);
        mailSender.setJavaMailProperties(properties);

        return mailSender;
    }





}
```

ThymeleafConfig:

```
public class ThymeleafConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter  {




    @Bean
    public ViewResolver viewResolver() {
        ThymeleafViewResolver viewResolver = new ThymeleafViewResolver();
        viewResolver.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
        viewResolver.setTemplateEngine( templateEngine());
        return viewResolver;
    }

    @Bean
    public ISpringTemplateEngine templateEngine() {
        SpringTemplateEngine templateEngine = new SpringTemplateEngine();
        templateEngine.setTemplateResolver(templateResolver());
        return templateEngine;
    }

    private ITemplateResolver templateResolver() {
        SpringResourceTemplateResolver templateResolver = new SpringResourceTemplateResolver();
        templateResolver.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
        templateResolver.setCacheable(false);
        templateResolver.setPrefix("classpath:/templates/");
        templateResolver.setSuffix(".html");
        templateResolver.setTemplateMode(TemplateMode.HTML);
        return templateResolver;
    }
}
```

I did it from this example : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KoPWOACk6CA

Answer (score 0):

Spring is complaining when attempting to construct your KonsultacjaController because it can't find a bean that satisfies the dependency on the MailComponent. From the classes you've included, it looks like it could be one of two things:

- Your spring context doesn't have a TemplateEngine instance. Your MailComponent requires one and if your context doesn't have it, it won't be able to construct the MailController (and thus won't be able to construct the KonsultacjaController).

or

- Spring component scanning isn't finding your MailController component and thus it doesn't exist in the context.

By the way, JavaMailSender extends MailSender so you shouldn't need to inject both into MailComponent.

Comment: Do i need to add ScanComponent?

Comment: It depends. If you're using SpringBoot and your components are in the same package (or a sub package) from where your main class is, you don't. Otherwise, you may need to add @ComponentScan(basePackages = {"yourPackageHere", "another package here"})    You do need to have a TemplateEngine somewhere in your context though (without that, no amount of scanning will help; it needs that to construct MailComponent).

Comment: I don 't quite understand, because it's in MailComponent

Comment: It's used in MailComponent. You declare it as Autowired. Anything you want spring to wire in needs to be provided by the context. So you need a Bean annotated method in your configuration class that constructs and returns am instance. Similar to what you did for the JavaMailSender in the MailConfig bean.

Comment: It have to lool like this?  @Bean
        public TemplateEngine templateEngine(){
        TemplateEngine templateEngine = new TemplateEngine();
        templateEngine.setTemplateResolver(thymeleafTemplateResolver());
        return templateEngine;
    }

Comment: I added all text of error. Maybe the problem is in some different thing.

Comment: Based on the error you added, it can't find a property called spring.mail.default-encoding. if you have an application.properties file in your resources directory, ensure you have a property with that key.

Comment: But i have this Bean in ThymeleafConfig

Answer (score 0):

As @Chris has suggested.

Look around **application.properties** or **application.yml** file.

There must be key defined as shown example below

**application.properties**

```
spring.mail.default-encoding=UTF-8
```

**application.yml**

```
spring
  mail
    default-encodig: UTF-8
```